# Identity Access if I add push notifications on my android application

Tags: java, android, parsing, parse-platform, push-notification

Since i added Push Notifications from Parse on my android application, when i install my application from google play, it says that the application needs access to Identity. Why is that?

Thank you

Comment: Interesting, because I created Android messaging app that uses Parse, and only used these permissions:INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WAKE_LOCK, VIBRATE, RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, GET_ACCOUNTS, com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE.  I wonder if they changed something recently.

Comment: I used the same as you in my manifest. But when i download my app from google play store, it says "The application needs access to -Identity and - wifi". I think that the google play store according to the permissions i gave in my manifest file, concluded that it need access to Identity.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is Google Play Store definition for the IDENTITY permission.  It makes sense that Parse.com would need IDENTITY permission to use Parse account, but not sure why this doesn't have to be defined in AndroidManifest.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en               An app can use your account and/or profile information on your device. Identity access may include the ability to:

Find accounts on the device
Read your own contact card (example: name and contact information)
Modify your own contact card
Add or remove accounts

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply